# wxPython: Using a GridBagSizer

Tags: python

I am a beginner to development in python, and I'm trying to create a simple application.

This application is supposed to show me a frame containing a `GridBagSize` that should load and position 4 buttons. However, the small problem that I encounter is that my 4 buttons are found very small in the upper left of the screen.

Just to clarify, I'm using Python 2.7.8 for Windows 32-bit and wxPython 2.8.12.1.

I am attaching my code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# import wx Module
import wx
# Creating a class derived from wx.Frame
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=title,style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        # Creating a GridBagSizer
        frameSizer=wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=5, hgap=5)
        # Creating buttons inside the frame and positioning them in the GridBagSizer
        Button1=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 1")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button1, pos=(0, 0), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button2=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 2")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button2, pos=(0, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button3=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 3")
        Button4=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_CLOSE, label="Button 4")
        self.SetSizer(frameSizer)
        #frameSizer.SetSizeHints(self)
        # We set our frame dimansions
        self.SetSize((400, 250))
        # Event of buttons ((Only the closing event for the Button4)
        Button4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
    # Creating the class method associated with the action of Button4
    def OnClose(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()
class MyApp(wx.App):
    """
    Specific class to the application created
    """
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=MyFrame("Example of a Small Program")
        # Display frame
        frame.Show(True)
        # We put the frame in main window
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True
    # Method of closing
    def OnExit(self):
        result=wx.MessageDialog(parent=None, message="Goodbye", caption="Exit", style=wx.OK)
        # Display dialog goodbye
        result.ShowModal()
# Program execution
app=MyApp(redirect=False)
app.MainLoop()
```

---

thank you for your quick response.

Yes, I forgot to add my buttons 3 and 4 in the frameSizer.

I put my insertion buttons code below.

At display, I still have my buttons which are reduced in the upper left of the screen.

About your suggestion to reduct span to 1 row and 1 col, I have the same result.

I think I have to use AddGrowableCol and AddGrowableRow methods but I do not know to use them.

With the GridSizer sizer, the frame is automatically resized.

Apparently this is not the case with the GridBagSizer?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards.

```
        # Creating buttons inside the frame and positioning them in the GridBagSizer
        Button1=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 1")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button1, pos=(0, 0), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button2=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 2")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button2, pos=(0, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button3=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 3")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button3, pos=(2, 0), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button4=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_CLOSE, label="Button 4")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button4, pos=(2, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.SetSizer(frameSizer)
```

Comment: I notice two issues with your code: 1) You didn't frameSizer.Add buttons 3 and 4.  2) You probably want to remove the span on Button 1 and 2.  That causes them each to use two slots in your GridBagSizer.

Answer (score 0):

First, I wanted to thank you for the help you have given me over the understanding of GridBagSizer.

I finally found a solution to my problem.

In fact, I used the **AddGrowableRow** and **AddGrowableCol** methods.

I reaffixable you my entire code hereunder,hoping that this will help the beginner like me.

If you find any error in this code, let me know.

Best regards.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# import wx Module
import wx
# Creating a class derived from wx.Frame
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        super(MyFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, id=wx.ID_ANY, title=title,style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE|wx.TAB_TRAVERSAL)
        # Creating a GridBagSizer
        frameSizer=wx.GridBagSizer(vgap=5, hgap=5)
        # Creating buttons inside the frame and positioning them in the GridBagSizer
        Button1=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 1")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button1, pos=(0, 0), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button2=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 2")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button2, pos=(0, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button3=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_ANY, label="Button 3")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button3, pos=(2, 0), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        Button4=wx.Button(parent=self, id=wx.ID_CLOSE, label="Button 4")
        frameSizer.Add(item=Button4, pos=(2, 1), span=(2, 1), flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTRE)
        self.SetSizer(frameSizer)
        frameSizer.SetSizeHints(self)
        # We resize our columns by the method AddGrowableCol
        for i in range(2):
            frameSizer.AddGrowableCol(i)
        # We resize our rows by the method AddGrowableRow
        for i in range(4):
            frameSizer.AddGrowableRow(i)
        # We set our frame dimansions
        self.SetSize((400, 250))
        # Event of buttons ((Only the closing event for the Button4)
        Button4.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnClose)
    # Creating the class method associated with the action of Button4
    def OnClose(self, evt):
        self.Destroy()
class MyApp(wx.App):
    """
    Specific class to the application created
    """
    def OnInit(self):
        frame=MyFrame("Example of a Small Program")
        # Display frame
        frame.Show(True)
        # We put the frame in main window
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)
        return True
    # Method of closing
    def OnExit(self):
        result=wx.MessageDialog(parent=None, message="Goodbye", caption="Exit", style=wx.OK)
        # Display dialog goodbye
        result.ShowModal()
# Program execution
app=MyApp(redirect=False)
app.MainLoop()
```